# Getting value undefined in axios call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, promise, axios

I have following code calling post and get API calls.

**Problem is I am getting customerDatas undefined..**

Any idea why this issue is.

```
try {
        let dataPromises = await axios.post('customers', {}, { baseURL: baseURL });
    
        var customerDatas = await Promise.all(dataPromises.data.customerIds.map( async (customerId) =>{
            await axios.get('customers/' + customerId, {baseURL : baseURL});
            console.log(customerDatas);
        })); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
```

Comment: 1. You forgot to return from the map's callback 2. You are trying to access a variable that doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Konrad Linkowski mention in the comments, you do not return anything from `map`:

```
var customerDatas = await Promise.all(dataPromises.data.customerIds.map( async (customerId) => {
  return axios.get('customers/' + customerId, {baseURL : baseURL});
}));
```

also, you cannot access `customerDatas` inside the map because it is not yet initalized.